# PowerShell module Posh-SSH - How to pass escape characters

Tags: powershell, posh-ssh

My first question here so sorry if I get the formatting wrong. I will try my best. I am using PowerShell and the Posh-SSH module.

I am trying to use PowerShell to SSH into a Citrix ADC (NetScaler). I am using the following code

```
$session = New-SSHSession -ComputerName nsr1.example.com
```

This works fine and I see the active connection.

I then use the follow command to send two commands, the first command goes into the FreeBSD shell of the ADC.

```
Shell
```

The second command is telnet *IP Port*

The whole command looks like

```
Invoke-SSHCommand -Command 'shell "telnet 192.168.57.14 8080"'
```

This then times out after a minute or less if i set the -Timeout option.

However here is my ask that I can't figure out.

If the connection is success I should get the following returned

```
telnet 1.2.3.4 8080
Trying 1.2.3.4...
Connected to FQDN.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

How do I pass the escape character.

(^]) using its ASCII code (0x1D), I tried passing it onto the end of command

```
Invoke-SSHCommand -Command 'shell "telnet 192.168.57.14 8080 [char]0x1D"'
```

I get presented with the Error being passed in the output

```
Invoke-SSHCommand -Command 'shell "telnet 1.2.3.4 8080 [char]0x1D"'
cmdlet Invoke-SSHCommand at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
SessionId[0]: 6
SessionId[1]: 


Host       : nsr1.example.com
Output     : {Warning: One or more RPC nodes are configured with default passwords. For enhanced security, you must change the default RPC node password.,  Done, ERROR: }
ExitStatus : 1
```

So I am assuming the ERROR is the escape character not working as I had hoped. If someone has any pointers on what I am missing that would be great.

Update - I have been been doing further reading and learning and am still struggling to get the escape sequence of ^] to be passed. I have tried the following commands

```
    Invoke-SSHCommand -SessionId "0" -Command 'shell "telnet 1.2.3.4 8080; ^]; \r"'
    and
    # Establish the telnet connection
    Invoke-SSHCommand -SessionId "0" -Command 'shell "telnet 1.2.3.4 8080"' -TimeOut 60
    #Wait for a moment
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
    #Send the escape character (^]) to interact with telnet session
Invoke-SSHCommand -SessionId "0" -Command 'shell "^]"'
    #Send the return/enter key to complete the interaction
Invoke-SSHCommand -SessionId "0" -Command 'shell "\r"'
```